# Prove or Disprove: $m^2-n^2=2$ where m and n are integers. (Checking)

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Prove or Disprove: The following statement: 
There are integers m and n such that
$m^2-n^2=2$
Solution:
$m^2-n^2=(m-n)(m+n)=2\times1$ 
Since 2 is a prime number, then

Case 1: $m-n=2$ and  $m+n=1$
Solve the two equations, then $m=\frac{3}{2}$ which is not integer.
Case 1: $m-n=1$ and  $m+n=2$
Solve the two equations, then $n=\frac{1}{2}$ which is not integer.
Therefore, there are no two integers m and n such that $m^2-n^2=2$
Note: This is a question from the test I just took. I am just checking if I did it right.

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: As you may suppose $m,n \ge 0$, the first case can't happen.

Comment: What do you mean? m and n need to be integers.

Answer (score 1):

A different approach. Consider modulo $4$. The possibilities on LHS are $0,1,3$ while RHS is $2$ modulo $4$. Hence no integer $m,n$ can satisfy.